# Ubuntu reboot system bring dirty bit to boot partition

Tags: ubuntu, efi

I have Acer Nitro 5 with NVMe SSD, i5 Kaby Lake, Intel 630 + NVidia 1050Ti, UEFI unsecure, singleboot.

I started to detect issues when switching to Intel graphics card. (failed to switch, then failed to reboot).

I dig deeper. I remember seeing "dirty bit" "damaged" boot partition/recovery (both FAT).

Then I see issues installing initramfs-tools. Again because boot partition is set "dirty bit". After repair the initramfs works, switching graphics card works.

So my culprit is that booting/restarting notebook often sets "dirty bit" on FAT partition. I tried reading latest log files (ls -ltr /var/log) but it's too much.

What can I do?

Comment: I think I've read somewhere that Linux always sets dirty flag on FAT partitions, because it's not documented when exactly it's supposed to be set and this is a safe default action. Don't know if it's still like this, though.

Comment: The dirty bit is set when the partition is mounted, and is unset when it is unmounted. If reboot/shutdown doesn't unset the dirty bit, the partition doesn't get properly unmounted. So find out why that happens, e.g. by reading the syslog to find out what happens during the shutdown, and why the automatic unmount isn't executed properly. There can be many possible reasons.